# Как работает неявное преобразование для std::function и std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, lambda, полиморфизм

Почему данный код работает? Лямбда же возвращает указатель на `Derived`, а в мапе мы ожидаем функцию, которая возвращает указатель на `Interface`.

```
struct Interface {};
struct Derived : Interface {};

int main() {
    using AggregatorCreator = std::function<std::unique_ptr<Interface> ()>;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, AggregatorCreator> aggregatorCreators;
    aggregatorCreators["test"] = []() {return std::make_unique<Derived> ();};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не указатель, а `std::function`. Это допустимо из за апкаста, там скорее всего на шаблон применён `std::is_convertible`. А `Derived*` к `Interface*` имплиситно кастится, так что подходит.

Comment: Указатель на `Derived` может быть неявно преобразован в указатель на `Interface`, так что результат выполнения лямбды без проблем используется в качестве результата выполнения `std::function`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Весь секрет скрыт в шаблонах `std::unique_ptr::unique_ptr` и `std::unique_ptr::operator=`:

```cpp
template<typename _Up, typename _Ep>
using __safe_conversion_up = __and_<
    is_convertible<typename unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::pointer, pointer>,
    __not_<is_array<_Up>>
>;

template<typename _Up, typename _Ep, typename = _Require<
    __safe_conversion_up<_Up, _Ep>,
    typename conditional<is_reference<_Dp>::value,
    is_same<_Ep, _Dp>,
    is_convertible<_Ep, _Dp>>::type>>
unique_ptr(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) noexcept
    : _M_t(__u.release(), std::forward<_Ep>(__u.get_deleter()))
{ }

template<typename _Up, typename _Ep>
typename enable_if< __and_<
    __safe_conversion_up<_Up, _Ep>,
    is_assignable<deleter_type&, _Ep&&>
>::value, unique_ptr&>::type
operator=(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) noexcept
{
    reset(__u.release());
    get_deleter() = std::forward<_Ep>(__u.get_deleter());
    return *this;
}
```

А также в способности `std::function` конвертировать возвращаемый тип в неявно конвертируемый:

```cpp
template<typename _Cond, typename _Tp>
    using _Requires = typename enable_if<_Cond::value, _Tp>::type;

template<typename _Func,
    typename _Res2 = __invoke_result<_Func&, _ArgTypes...>>
struct _Callable
    : __is_invocable_impl<_Res2, _Res>::type
{ };

template<typename _Functor,
    typename = _Requires<__not_<is_same<_Functor, function>>, void>,
    typename = _Requires<_Callable<_Functor>, void>>
function(_Functor);

template<typename _Functor>
_Requires<_Callable<typename decay<_Functor>::type>, function&>
operator=(_Functor&& __f) {
    function(std::forward<_Functor>(__f)).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

Проверка на конвертируемость:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Interface {};
struct Derived : Interface {};

template<typename T>
using UPtr = std::unique_ptr<T>;

template<typename T>
using FuncPtr = std::function<T*()>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << std::is_convertible_v<Derived*,Interface*>
              << std::endl
              << std::is_convertible_v<UPtr<Derived>,UPtr<Interface>>
              << std::endl
              << std::is_convertible_v<Derived*(*)(),Interface*(*)()>
              << std::endl
              << std::is_convertible_v<FuncPtr<Derived>,FuncPtr<Interface>>
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
true
true
false
true
```